# Android : How to update API level in developer console without updating the app?

Tags: android

I lost my keystore, so cannot update the app.
Can I somehow, update the API levels which are currently 11-19 to 11-23 ?
In developer console I do not see an option to update the API levels.
[image: No option to edit API level]

Comment: You can't do that, it would mean that the Google Play store would have to open your apk, change the versions and then sign the apk back with your key(which you have).

Comment: Actually, I saw my code, there API level is 11-23, but on Developer Console, it is written 11-19.
This is causing my app showing as 'not compatible' on API level 20, 21, 22 and 23 devices.